# Use case of method overriding in PHP

Tags: java, php

I am from Java background and currently learning PHP. I was reading about "method overriding" in PHP. I do not understand the use-case of method overriding in PHP. In Java all the magic happens at run-time that is we can use "method overriding" for "run-time polymorphism". In PHP it is just same function name (I know in PHP there is no data type) in parent and child.

edit:I want to know use-case for example in java I can define area method in parent class and at run-time it decides whether to calculate area of square or triangle depending on child reference.So on the similar line I am looking for explanation.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394986/php-oop-method-overriding-the-dry-way?rq=1   I also referred this link and it helped me.Thanks.

Comment: As I have got the answer and question is on hold so should I delete it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you are asking, but I think you just want a `php` example of method overriding.

The Java case, where for instance you have a parent with 2 parameters and you have a child with with an extra parameter is not possible. But a different implementation of the same function is possible obviously.

So a parent

```
class parent
{

   protected function doStuff()
   {
      echo 'parent stuff';
   }
}
```

and a child

```
class child extends parent
{

    /**
     * @overrides parent function
     */
     protected function doStuff()
     {
        echo "child stuff";
     }
}
```

so that's what you have. I'm not sure what part you are unclear about: you have less options in PHP then in Java (so declaring aN overriding function with a different footprint is not allowed), you cannot have 2 functions with different parameter counts in the same or in child classes.

But you can do above if you need it. Add extra steps (for instance, the child is a class that has a counter of called functions in it, so apart from calling teh parent 'doStuff', it can increment the internal counter. That would be a random usecase.

Comment: Thanks for your response but I want to know use-case for example in java I can define area method in parent class and at run-time it decides whether to calculate area of square or triangle depending on child reference.So on the similar line I am looking for explanation.

Comment: That's what I gave you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394986/php-oop-method-overriding-the-dry-way?rq=1   I also referred this link and got your point.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Implementation of overriding in php is very easy. If your parent class has a function. You can create function with same name in your child class to override the function. Implementation of overriding can not be achieved by creating 2 function with same name and different argument in php. Because we can not create same name function more than 1 time in php class. To implement overloading we need to take help of magic method in php.

```
class testParent
{
  public function f1()
   {
     echo 1;
   }
  public function f2()
   {
     echo 2;
   }
}
class testChild
{
  function f2($a) //overriding function f2
   {
     echo "$a";
   }
}
$a = new testChild();
$a->f2("Tushar");//it will print tushar
```

To override built-in functions in php you can use `override_function`

```
bool override_function ( string $function_name , string $function_args , string $function_code )
```

Comment: Note that override_function requires the [Advanced PHP Debugger (APD)](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.apd.php) enabled, which isn't recommended for a production environment

Comment: @MarkBaker yes I know that ... but I wrote this just to show him options...as I dont know how the OP author will use it